# How to get page load time from har file in python?

Tags: python, selenium, har, browsermob-proxy

I'm trying to get the page load time. I'm using BrowserMob Proxy with selenium to generate the HAR file and haralyzer to read the HAR file. Details and error log is [here](https://github.com/mrname/haralyzer/issues/13),

Please suggest if there are any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `requests` for this purpose as follow:

```
import requests
requests.get('http://requiredURL.com').elapsed.total_seconds()
```

This will return number of seconds that passed to load required page

Comment: elapsed.total_seconds() will give only server response time. I do not think this is the solution for the question.